# We are using triggers for reg_Date and upd_Date to be inserted along with the required data the upd_date will be inserted in UTC 0:00 timestamp

Tags: oracle, timezone-offset

How to convert that date to the CET time and fetch that appropriate upd_date from below select statement.

```
SELECT MAX(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(upd_date,'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MI:SS'),'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MI:SS')) AS MAX_UPD_DATE
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE user_id='SOMEVALUE';
```

the upd_date store in MY_TABLE will be displaying as result. But i don't want UTC +0:00 time . i want CET time (Europe/stockholm)
Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SWITCHOFFSET()` in `SQL` to change the datetimeoffset to whichever timezone you prefer.

This change will not affect the original datetimeoffset according to MDN. See link [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677244.aspx)

For example,

```
SELECT SWITCHOFFSET(column_name, '-05:00') FROM my_table
```

For `Oracle`, there are functions you can use. For example, 
`TZ_OFFSET(timezone)`  [Documentation](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/tz_offset.php)
or

```
SELECT FROM_TZ(column_name, 'US/Eastern') AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London'
```

Here is more information on the AT TIME ZONE clause. [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1007699).
If you want to see all the timezones available, you can run this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tzname FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES;
```

The one thing I do not recommend is adding or subtracting dates because that's prone to more errors.

Answer (score 0):

select SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'CET' from dual;
This worked for me